# Adding an iframe by JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to get javascript which adds iframe by Javascript. It create iframe before  tag.

You can see [jsfiddle demo.](http://url.funtwixt.com/6)
But I dont want to add  tag. I just want to add external .js file which do all things on its own!

Comment: you do not want <iframe> tag in your code?

Comment: I dont want to add anything like <div> in html file
I would just add <link .... >of js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
var newElem = createElement('script');
newElem.setAttribute('src',      'http://example.com/js/script.js');
newElem.setAttribute('type',     'text/javascript');
newElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript');
document.getElementById('IdFromTheHeadElem').appendChild(newElem);
```

Comment: how would it end up before </body> tag??

Comment: of course it will be end bevor the elements there you added ends

Answer (score 0):

You can create the tag with

`document.write("<iframe..............>");`

Edit:
The solution i wrote in the comments in jQuery:

In your JS file:

```
$(function(){
    $('#container').html('<iframe........');
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<div id="#container"></div>
```

Include it in your header with:

```
<script src=".............yourscriptname.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would add javascript file link in head... as i said in comment of my question

Comment: If you load the file into your header you have to wait until the dom is loaded (dom ready event) and select a item which should contain the iframe (a empty div for example) with "getElementById" then you can set the html source in this eleme nt with "innerHTML". I suggest you to use a library like jQuery because especially the dom ready event is difficult to implement in plain javascript (browser compatibility). If you want to avoid the dom ready event you have to write a function coll into your html source at the position the code should appear.

Answer (score 0):

From your jsfiddle it looks like you should be doing this (in plain JS) to avoid defining iframe directly in the HTML code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = 'iframeID';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
// the rest is manipulating this iframe
iframe.contentDocument.write("<html><head></head><body><div id='foo'>The div</div></body></html>");
iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "Greetings from outside!";
```

[code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfDyq/8/) (I wrapped the code there in a closure to prevent polluting the global namespace)

The `document.body.appendChild(iframe);` should be changed to something else depending where you want to place it inside the page (e.g. `document.getElementById('some-div-id').appendChild(iframe);`)